# Regex to remove whitepsace except when it is inside " "

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking everywhere but can't find the answer. I need a regex which removes all spaces in a string but keeps only the ones that are inside `""`.
Example: `$F:2 $PX:30 $PY:980 $T: " "` or `$F:A $PX:30B $PY:9K80 $T: " "` so in the end it should look like `$F:2$PX:30$PY:980$T:" "`

It would be valuable to explain how to read the regex that you answer.

Comment: honestly this isn't a very difficult problem to solve by just iterating over the characters and keeping track of opening and closing double quotes instead of using a regular expression.

Comment: You provide little sample case. Can there occure other than whitespace wihin quotes eg `"a b c"`... [see this demo](https://regex101.com/r/XtILna/1). Please also show what you've tried already for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match whitespace which is touching a `"`, yet not enclosed by them.

```
" +(?!\")|(?<!\") +"
```

And for all white space:

```
"\s+(?!\")|(?<!\")\s+"
```

You can test it on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Cbp6ET/1) or [Rextester](http://rextester.com/IJLUX11928)

Comment: can you please make a little update. `$F:2 $PX:30 $PY:980 $T:" " $F:2 $PX:30 $PY:980 $T:" "` in thise case the regex doesn't catch the space after the closing ". Can you make it to catch that too? It's not an error, soemtimes the string is like that, like 2 in 1

Comment: ok. the problem is like this: how I wrote in the first comment, after the first `$T:""` it ignores the rest, it gives me only the half of the string. So can you find a workaround to get that too @maksymiuk

Comment: I don't understand.. here in this example it shows that it is working as you wanted: https://regex101.com/r/4ggez2/1

Comment: Check the Rextester link i just added

Comment: it seems that the problems occur when there is a space before the opening ", then it doesn't recognize `$T: " "` as part of the string. @maksymiuk

Comment: yes, it works, but there is a space before the opening ", which I haven't seen when making the question. now that space is causing me troubles cuz it separates it from the string, ignoring it totally

Comment: What is 'it' in this case? and what is being 'ignored' ? because i am not understanding. Orignially you wanted a result of `$F:2$PX:30$PY:980$T:" "` and my regex gets you that result.

Comment: ok, sorry. I think what I'm trying to do now goes beyond the scope of the question

Comment: Well explain it, i may be able to solve it. Im just trying to understand

Comment: There is this code [link]https://regex101.com/r/oplqct/1 where you can see it catches the second `$T:" "` because there is no space before the opening ", but it doesn't catch the first `$T: ""`. hope you understand now

Comment: Well i don't know who's regex your using there but it's definitely not mine. Heres what happens when i put my regex in there: https://regex101.com/r/zSifcL/1

Comment: no, it's not your regex. I got messed up in my mind. sorry, and thank you

Answer (score 1):

Matching a space not preceeded nor followed by quotation mark:

```
(?<!") (?!")
```

Matching all whitespace:

```
(?<!")\s+(?!")
```

Note: This might not work on more than one space, as pointed out by Dmitry.

Comment: This would fail on 3+ consecutive spaces in quotes, e.g. `"   "`.

Comment: can you modify it a bit to just ignore the spaces that are preceded by quotation and remove the spaces that are followed by quotation mark, I need to find this to `$T: " "` and not not just `$T:" "`. Hope you understand what I'm trying to say

Comment: @arianitax , my answer solves that problem, also allows for multiple spaces

Comment: @DmitryEgorov Thanks for pointing that out. I put that into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[The Greatest Regex Trick Ever](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) is quite helpful in such cases:

```
var str = "$F:2 $PX:30 $PY:980 \"   \"$T:\" \"";
str = Regex.Replace(str, "\"\\s+\"|\\s+", m => { return m.Value.StartsWith("\"") ? m.Value : ""; });
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q54FlJ